# How to change tick label font size

Tags: python, matplotlib, format, xticks, yticks

In a matplotlib figure, how can I make the font size for the tick labels using `ax1.set_xticklabels()` smaller?

Further, how can one rotate it from horizontal to vertical?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Please note that newer versions of MPL have a shortcut for this task. An example is shown in the other answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11386056/42346

The code below is for illustrative purposes and may not necessarily be optimized.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def xticklabels_example():
    fig = plt.figure() 

    x = np.arange(20)
    y1 = np.cos(x)
    y2 = (x**2)
    y3 = (x**3)
    yn = (y1,y2,y3)
    COLORS = ('b','g','k')

    for i,y in enumerate(yn):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(len(yn),1,i+1)

        ax.plot(x, y, ls='solid', color=COLORS[i]) 

        if i != len(yn) - 1:
            # all but last 
            ax.set_xticklabels( () )
        else:
            for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
                tick.label.set_fontsize(14) 
                # specify integer or one of preset strings, e.g.
                #tick.label.set_fontsize('x-small') 
                tick.label.set_rotation('vertical')

    fig.suptitle('Matplotlib xticklabels Example')
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xticklabels_example()
```

[image]

Answer (score 812):

There is a simpler way actually. I just found:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# We prepare the plot  
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# We change the fontsize of minor ticks label 
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=10)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=8)
```

This only answers to the size of `label` part of your question though.

Comment: Use `axis = 'x'` or  `axis = 'y'` to modify just one of the axis

Comment: Question Part 2: Use `labelrotation=<float>` -> `ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=10, labelrotation=90)` [api-docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params)

Answer (score 363):

To specify both font size and rotation at the same time, try this:

```
plt.xticks(fontsize=14, rotation=90)
```

Answer (score 88):

Another alternative

I have two plots side by side and would like to adjust tick labels separately.

The above solutions were close however they were not working out for me. I found my solution from this matplotlib [page](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Increasing-font-size-in-axis-ticks-td27274.html).

```
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)
```

This did the trick and was straight to the point. For my use case, it was the plot on the right that needed to be adjusted. For the plot on the left since I was creating new tick labels I was able to adjust the font in the same process as **set**ing the labels.

ie

```
ax1.set_xticklabels(ax1_x, fontsize=15)
ax1.set_yticklabels(ax1_y, fontsize=15)
```

thus I used for the right plot,

```
ax2.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=24)
ax2.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=24)
```

A minor subtlety... I know... but I hope this helps someone :)

Bonus points if anyone knows how to adjust the font size of the order of magnitude label.

[image]

Answer (score 76):

Alternatively, you can just do:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
label_size = 8
mpl.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = label_size
```

Answer (score 53):

```
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=12)
```

Answer (score 24):

In current versions of Matplotlib, you can do `axis.set_xticklabels(labels, fontsize='small')`.

Answer (score 19):

The following worked for me:

```
ax2.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=7)
ax2.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=7)
```

The advantage of the above is you do not need to provide the `array` of `labels` and works with any data on the `axes`.

Answer (score 18):

For smaller font, I use

`ax1.set_xticklabels(xticklabels, fontsize=7)`

and it works!

Answer (score 15):

You can also change label display parameters like fontsize with a line like this:

```
zed = [tick.label.set_fontsize(14) for tick in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()]
```

Comment: I think that using list comprehensions that have side effects is not the best practice. I'd suggest using a standard for loop instead.