# How do I change the font size of the scale in matplotlib plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

While plotting using Matplotlib, I have found how to change the font size of the labels.
But, how can I change the size of the numbers in the scale?

For clarity, suppose you plot x^2 from (x0,y0) = 0,0 to (x1,y1) = (20,20).
The scale in the x-axis below maybe something like

> 0   1   2  ...   20.

I want to change the font size of such scale of the x-axis.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Matplotlib refers to these as xtick labels. They can be changed in a large number of different ways, passed in as parameters, or iterated through and edited (as in the case of the solution posted here [Matplotlib make tick labels font size smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390393/matplotlib-make-tick-labels-font-size-smaller)).

I went ahead and posted a more concise solution, as the former was very inefficient.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import math

def setLabelExample():
    fig = pyplot.figure() 
    x = [i for i in range(200)]
    y = [xi**2 for xi in x]

    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax.plot(x, y) 
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=30)
    fig.suptitle('Matplotlib xticklabels Example')
    pyplot.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLabelExample()
```

Comment: Thank you! I should add that the method tick_params also work for the whole figure, not only for subplots.

Answer (score 0):

### simply put, you can use the following command to set the range of the ticks and change the size of the ticks

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

### set the range of ticks for x-axis and y-axis

plt.set_yticks(range(0,24,2))

plt.set_xticks(range(0,24,2))

### change the size of ticks for x-axis and y-axis

plt.yticks(fontsize=12,)

plt.xticks(fontsize=12,)