# Changing size of scientific notation tick labels in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot, insets

I am plotting an inset into a bigger figure and I have a problem with resizing the ticks for both axes for the inset.

I have looked at this question [Matplotlib make tick labels font size smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390393/matplotlib-make-tick-labels-font-size-smaller) and managed to resize ticks.

However, my ticks are plotted using scientific notation on both axes (automatically) and while that is not a problem the '1e-7' label doesn't resize with the rest of the ticks and it superimposes with the x axis label.

Can someone tell me how to change the size of the '1e-7'? I can't find a way!

Here is the code and the figure that is causing me problems.

```
logN = lognorm(s=[sigma], loc=0, scale=exp(mu))
domain = np.linspace(logN.ppf(0.01), logN.ppf(0.99), 250)

ax2.set_title('uncertainty', size = 'x-small')
ax2.set_xlabel('exceedance frequency', size = 'x-small')
ax2.set_ylabel('probability', size= 'x-small')
ax2.tick_params( axis = 'both', which ='major', labelsize = 7)
ax2.plot(domain, logN.pdf(domain))
```

[image: inset that causes problems]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use the `ax.yaxis.get_offset_text()` method to return the text object and then set it with `set_fontsize(7)`. Try:

```
tx = ax2.xaxis.get_offset_text()
tx.set_fontsize(7)
```

Alternatively, if you'd like to remove the offsets and then add them at a position of your choice, then use:

```
tx.set_visible(False)
ax2.text(1.1, -.1, "1e-7", fontsize=7)
```

You may have to fiddle with the x and y positions manually until it looks good.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!