# matplotlib change size of unit on axis label

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to change the appearacnce (font/size) of the units in axis label. below is an example of the plot, so, I wanna to change the appearance of unit(e.g. m/c*g/cc)

```
#
plt.subplot2grid((2,3), (1,0), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
s  = plt.scatter(Ip , Is , c=time , s=10, cmap='tab10', 
                 norm=mpl.colors.SymLogNorm(linthresh=10),marker = 's')
plt.xlabel(r'$I_p(m/s*g/cc)$')
plt.ylabel(r'$I_sI_p(m/s*g/cc)$')
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390393/matplotlib-make-tick-labels-font-size-smaller

Answer (score 0):

From the MatPlotLib documentation, this is suggested:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

font = {'family' : 'normal',
        'weight' : 'bold',
        'size'   : 22}

plt.xlabel('font', **font)
plt.ylabel('font', **font)
```