# Overlapping y axis lable in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have these code here to create an xgboost feature importance plot with more than 40 variables :

```
plot_importance(xgb_model)
plt.show()
```

However, I got a plot with overlapping y-axis labels and it was hard to read. The `figsize=()` argument did not seem to work.
[image]

Is there a way to make this plot readable?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely go with `figsize`. You can see that because if you interactively change the window size you observe that the ticks labels d on't overlap anymore.

You can also change the font properties, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11386056/13636407.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot_sin(figsize):

    x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi)
    y = np.sin(x)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)

    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-1.15, 1.15, 0.05))
    ax.set_title(f"{figsize = }")


plot_sin(figsize=(12, 4))
plot_sin(figsize=(12, 10))

plt.show()
```

[image: figsize 12 4]

[image: figsize 12 10]